# Approximation of monotone Sobolev functions

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $f\in W_{loc}^{1,2}(\mathbb R^2)$  be a continuous monotone **(real valued)** function (monotone in the sense that the maximum and minimum of $f$ in a precompact open set are attained at the boundary).

Is it true that there exists a sequence of smooth **monotone** functions $f_n$ converging to $f$ in $W^{1,2}_{loc}(\mathbb R^2)$? We could ask the same question for Sobolev functions in a ball.

This works, for example, if $f$ is a quasiconformal map (which is of course complex valued) with a compactly supported Beltrami coefficient. Then there exist smooth quasiconformal approximations to $f$.

I am also aware of this [result](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00205-011-0404-4) by Iwaniec, Kovalev, & Onninen which allows the approximation of Sobolev homeomorphisms of planar domains by diffeomorphisms (so in particular monotone smooth maps) in the Sobolev norm.

Comment: Nice question. Do you know the answer by now? Do you work with Mario Bonk?

Comment: Yes, I am working with Mario Bonk. I still do not know the answer to the question. The method used by Iwaniec, Kovalev & Onninen does not seem to work directly, but it seems that one should partition the domain of $f$ suitably and solve the Laplace equation in each region of the partition.

Comment: Do you have an answer to your question? I am very interested in it. I do not know if it is of any interest to you, but I have a paper about approximation by locally monotone functions: P. Hajlasz, J. Maly,  Ark. Mat. 40 (2002), 245--274. You can download it from: http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/Publications3.html

Comment: Any update on this? We have proven a coarea inequality for monotone Sobolev functions, so this could seriously be related.

Comment: Yes, monotone $W^{1,2}$ functions in a planar domain can be approximated by smooth monotone functions in the Sobolev norm. This is proved in this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00205-020-01563-x, which by the way you cite in your recent paper on the co-area inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has been answered by the OP in
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00205-020-01563-x